# when enter is hit add string to the end of the line

Tags: java, swing, return, append, jtextarea

In my java code below it produces a frame with a jtextrea. This allows for simple text processing. All I want to do is add "     Sam". Which is 5 spaces with sam at the end. Every time the user hits enter. You can see also the gif I added below which is exactly what I am looking for.

[image]

```
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
class text11 extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 



    // JFrame 
    static JFrame f; 



    // text area 
    static JTextArea jt; 

    // main class 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // create a new frame to store text field and button 
        f = new JFrame("textfield"); 

        // create a label to display text 




        // create a object of the text class 
        text11 te = new text11(); 



        // create a text area, specifying the rows and columns 
        jt = new JTextArea(" ", 20, 20); 

        JPanel p = new JPanel(); 

        // add the text area and button to panel 
        p.add(jt); 

        f.add(p); 
        // set the size of frame 
        f.setSize(300, 300); 

        f.show(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 

}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To get input so you know when the use hits enter, you have to create your own `KeyListener` class. If you don't know how to use it, here is a handy link from the documentation you can use: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html.

But simply put, an `KeyListener` is an interface where you have to specify a few methods, but in your case I think the only one you need is `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`(which is called pressed). If you're interested in the others, `keyReleased(KeyEvent e)` is when a key gets released, and `keyType(KeyEvent e)` is when it's pressed and released quickly. Then, use `JFrames` `addKeyListener(KeyListener k)` to add your custom action listener.

After you did that, you can use `JTextArea`'s `setText()` and `getText()` method to append "     sam" to the end (the 5 spaces get cut of by stack overflow, I know you want 5 spaces).

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
        jt.setText(jt.getText() + "     sam");
    }
}
```

If you added the `KeyListener` correctly, you should be fine!

Comment: Never use a KeyListener with a text component. Ever. If you need to listen to keys in a text component (e.g., a JTextarea), use Key Bindings which is how Swing handles key presses in these components. Better still, listen for changes in the component's Document, either after placement via a DocumentListener or here during placement via a DocumentFilter.

Comment: You would also not use getText() and setText(). That is not efficient. The getText() method has to parse the Document to create a String and then the setText() method has to parse the string to add the text back to the Document. Instead you would use the append() method.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String actionKey = "ADD_SAM";
    InputMap inputMap = jt.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
    KeyStroke enterPressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
    inputMap.put(enterPressed, actionKey);
    jt.getActionMap().put(actionKey, new TextAction(actionKey) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            jt.append(" Sam\n");
        }
    });
```

Comment: (1+) Using key bindings and the append() method is the better solution.